# JMeter - Keep current Threats Active

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I want to ask a question regarding of how to perform my load test scenarios. I have multiple threat groups that each one executes a scenario (get,post,put requests) with a different number of threats on each scenario. Each scenario takes an X (unknown) of time to be execute always depending of how many requests it has. What i want is to run them all together and hold the load (keep threats active) for a specific amount of time.

Let me give an example:

- Threat Group 1 - v. users 75
- Threat Group 2 - v. users 50
- Threat Group 3 - v. users 30

I want to execute all threat groups together and keep the load for 30 mins. The problem that i have its lets say that threat group 1 it takes only 2 mins to be executed, threat group 2 takes only 3 minutes and threat group 3 takes only 1 minute. I can not have the Infinite option tick as i have only specific number of data that i can use. For the first scenario i have 75 users (data) that if they execute the scenario once they can not execute it again thus i need 75 more (data) which i dont have.

Is there any way to do that? Is it feasible to keep threats alive in each threat group for specific amount of time? Or something that will execute the requests in a specific amount of time that will cover the whole duration? (30 mins)

Setting up the parameters in threat groups like the picture below when each scenario ends it shuts down its threats so i will never have lets say 30 v users to run in parallel for a specific amount of time.

[image]

[image]

The below graph shows that Scenario 1 (pink) ended its threats faster than Scenario 2 (ref). Here the settings are the following:

1. Threats in each scenario 5
2. Ramp-up 10 secs
3. Duration 90 secs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are constrainded by data and you have one data point for one loop per user . So I will try to manipulate rampup and set it to 1800 and loop = 1 for every thread group. Uncheck "specify thread lifetime". Jmeter will run new thread e.g for TG_1 every 1800/75 second. Whole test will run 1800sec + time for loop for last thread. If have to tink if this load profile is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  As i understood this is not the correct way right? The correct way is to have more data and loop threat groups until it reach the specify duration. The problem is that even having different ramp-up time some threats will end earlier as they require less time to finish all the requests hence some of them will finish earlier

Comment: Suppose we have the same amount of users in each group some threat groups will finish earlier than the other hence i will not have a consistency. Is like the last picture that i added.

Comment: yes - but the same rampup in every TG will impose roughly the same time for test so it may be workaround in your case.Also remember that jmeter will use shorter time for test duration if you have "specify thread lifetime" so condition to stop test is:  If Loop Count is not -1 or Forever, duration will be min(Duration, Loop Count * iteration duration)  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62914

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand your query, you have data for say 75 users, the data cannot be repeated. And you need to hold the load for 30 minutes.

In simple words, I can say that you cannot hold the load for this much time unless you have more data, or you can repeat data.

If 75 users are taking only 1 minute or even 5 minutes, this means that you have not added human reaction time. To add that, you can simply use timers. Which will delay the execution of sampler.

Answer (score 1):

If your first thread group executes 75 requests in 2 minutes and you want it to be executed in 30 minutes the only way of achieving this is making JMeter 15x times slower. JMeter provides a variety of [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) and each of them allows introducing delays between requests mainly to simulate real user ["think time"](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time)

75 requests in 2 minutes is approx 37 requests per minute and if you need to make it 15x times slower you need to execute ~2.4 requests per minute.

So you can add i.e. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to your first thread group and configure it like:

[image]

this way you will get 72 requests in 30 minutes.

Similarly you can slow down 2 remaining thread groups

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Ultimate Thread group plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

Use different ultimate thread group and change the threads as per your requirement but keep other parameters same as shown below.
So, your threads will vary but other condition probably will remain same. Like Initial delay, startup time, holdloadfor sec and shutdown.

[image]

You can use [plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) to download the jpgc@stardard set for all the plugin provided by jpgc. Then, you will get option to add jpgc ultimate thread group from Threads(Users) or from the same place we add normal/standard threadgroup.